# How send a form with Javascript when input name is "submit"?

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit

**Question:** How can you send a form with Javascript if one form input has the name `submit`?

**Background:** I am redirecting the user to another page with a hidden HTML form. I cannot change name on the (hidden) inputs, since the other page is on another server and the inputs need to be exactly as they are. My HTML form looks like this:

```html
<form id="redirectForm" method="post" action="http://www.example.com/">
  <input name="search" type="hidden" value="search for this" />
  <input name="submit" type="hidden" value="search now" />
</form>
```

I use the following javascript line to send the form automatically today:

```js
document.getElementById('redirectForm').submit();
```

However, since the name of one input is "submit" (it cannot be something else, or the other server won't handle the request), `document.getElementById('redirectForm').submit` refers to the input as it overrides the form function `submit()`.

The error message in Firefox is: `Error: document.getElementById("requestform").submit is not a function`. Similar error message in Safari.

Comment: Have you tried with `document.getElementById('redirectForm').submit.click()`? :P

Comment: @Stefan I'm sorry, but it doesn't submit the form. The input with the name `submit` does not have the type attribute `submit` or `button` but `hidden`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

***Worth noting***: It's often a lot easier to just change the input name to something other than "submit". Please use the solution below only if that's really not possible.

You need to get the `submit` function from a different form:

```
document.createElement('form').submit.call(document.getElementById('redirectForm'));
```

If you have already another `<form>` tag, you can use it instead of creating another one.

Comment: I think it's a waste to create an element just to get a function of it. I'm not sure if you did that for cross-browser reasons, but what about just `var theForm = document.getElementById('redirectForm'); theForm.constructor.prototype.submit.call(theForm);`?

Comment: @pimvdb It seems to work in Firefox 9, Safari 5 and Internet Explorer 9, too.

Comment: Even better: `HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(document.getElementById('redirectForm'))`. After all, `HTMLFormElement` is the equivalent of `theForm.constructor`.

Comment: @SLaks I've edited your answer because it's now a duplicate candidate. Feel free to rollback if you disagree with me.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) method from `HTMLFormElement.prototype`:

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(document.getElementById('redirectForm'));
```

Comment: Seems to work for me (FF66, Chromium 72). Actually seems cleaner than the accepted answer, too.

Comment: Might be even cleaner (not requiring to hardcode the prototype to use) to do something like `var form = document.getElementById('redirectForm'); form.__proto__.submit.call(form)`. Works on FF66 and Chromium 72, but probably everywhere. I guess this still breaks when there's a field named `__proto__`, but that seems acceptable.