# Why Form doesn't submit with javascript if an input field's name is submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Why Form doesn't submit on event if input field name is submit.
I already know it won't based on recent experience, but why not.

http://jsfiddle.net/btm5j599/1/

**Edited Code**

```js
$('#btn1').click(function() {
  $('#form1').attr('action', '');
  $('#form1').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="http://mytestsite.com/test/" method="post" id='form1'>
  <span>This is a form content</span>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<hr>

<button id="btn1">Submit form on same page</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How send a form with Javascript when input name is "submit"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729319/how-send-a-form-with-javascript-when-input-name-is-submit)

Comment: First things first: what's the question here?

Comment: The question is why is the form not submitting, when the button is clicked, if the name of the submit input is 'submit'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the submit button has the name `submit` and this clash is overriding the form's `submit()` function.

If you remove the name="submit" attribute, this will work.

Here is some more information on conflicts:

http://jibbering.com/faq/names

http://paulsec.github.io/blog/2014/03/09/dealing-with-html-submits-conflict

Comment: this is some legacy code, it had the names as is. the form actually have an action, for a reason i'm setting action to empty and post it to same page. but i didn't know the reason for not submitting the form when there is an input with name submit

Comment: It will work ok if you submit the form by pressing the submit button, but because of the name clash, you cannot post it by calling $('form').submit();

Comment: +1, very strange for me a variable scope is conflicting with a function name. i get it is conflicting but why this behavior is still mysterious to me.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is strange. I know it is legacy code, but if the name is not being used by the code, can you not remove it. Names of submit buttons were usually given like this out of habit.

Comment: Yes, can & will change the code. actually already did before posting the question. After banging my head for 2 hours, i wanted to know the reason of this behavior. Can you point me to the reason for such a conflict which in my opinion is stupid.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to put an hidden button (input type="submit") and trigger a "click" event on it instead of a "submit" event on the form

Comment: This is a nice idea and i'll remember this. I was looking for the reason why it does so. updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the js when you have an action that goes to www.google.com ?
What are you trying to do ?

If it's just a sample, I still don't understand why you need an input with the type submit?
You can have the button without a form and then run the js. But you can't run both because when you klick the input, it will bring you to google.com without running the js.
But you could open it in a new tab and then the js would run.

Comment: This is something you want to write as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting, now it takes even longer to be able to comment

Comment: @Sundaze It's a Catch 22 situation!

Answer (score 1):

Run the following modified submit along with a javascript console. There is a cross-origin policy error and also you were missing `http://`.

```js
  $('#form1').submit(function(event) {
    console.log(this.action);
    var action = this.action
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize()).done(function(data, status, xhr) {
      alert(action + "\n\n" + status);
    }).fail(function(xhr, status, err){
      alert(action + "\n\n" + status);
    });
  });

  $('h3').click(function() {
    $('#form1').submit();
  });
```

```css
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="http://www.google.com" method="post" id='form1'>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<h3>click</h3>
```