# Why the form not submitting using JavaScript when input name called submit?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

I have the following form. When I have the input name set to `submit`, it won't submit the form, why is that?

```
<form id="login" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="someval">
    <input type="hidden" name="userpass" value="somepass">
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Login">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var timeout = 12;
  setTimeout(function () {
      document.getElementById('login').submit();
  }, timeout);
</script>
```

Error message is:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function(…)

I guess the submit name is erasing the submit function in some way?

JSFiddle [with](https://jsfiddle.net/uz8vvdpg/) and [without](https://jsfiddle.net/uz8vvdpg/1/) submit name.

### edit to my question:

How can I submit the form using js when it includes input named submit?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516880/javascript-errors-reference-what-does-this-error-mean

Comment: as I thought the submit name erase for some reason the submit function because when I document.getElementById('login').userpass it gives me the userpass input element same as with the submit

Comment: looks like it is duplicate question after all and the best solution is:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729319/how-send-a-form-with-javascript-when-input-name-is-submit#answer-34525540

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has a single namespace for properties and methods. Each named field becomes a property of the form object. In your case, `document.getElementById('login').submit` is no longer a method, but an input field.

Answer (score 1):

Because you may access child elements of the form as direct properties. So in your case:

```
'use strict';
let form = document.getElementById('login');
console.log(form.username, form.userpass, form.submit); // 3 input elements
```

So when you have an element named `submit`, it shadows the `submit()` function, and thus you get the error about it not being a function.

Comment: thank you I understand that, so how can I js submit form with input named submit?

Comment: [How send a form with Javascript when input name is "submit"?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8729319). Or in short: Don't have an element named submit.